# In C89, I can't seem to make a character array from an existing one

Tags: c, c89

So my code breaks down at  buffer[i] = envp[i].

I want to create a char**buffer of the environment variables, and make them lower case (didn't add the putc(tolower()) yet loop). But when I just try to make buffer[i] = envp[i], the compiler returns me this error:

> error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]
>            buffer[i] = envp[i];
>                      ^
>
> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>            printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
>                    ~^     ~~~~~~~~~
>                    %d

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char * envp[])
{
    int i = 0;

    char *buffer = NULL;

    while(envp[i])
    {
        i++;
    }

    buffer = (char *)malloc(i * 8);


    for (i = 0; envp[i] != 0 ; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = envp[i];
        printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
        printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Please help, I've been breaking my head here :( . Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Given `char *buffer`, what do you think `buffer[i]` is?

Comment: Even if `buffer` is changed to be a sequence of `char *` rather than `char` as it is now, nothing is being copied except the pointers from `evp[]`. In short, it's *shallow* copying. Where originally you had one set of pointers pointing to those strings (in `evp[]`), now you would have two (in `evp[]` and `buffer[]`). I somewhat doubt that accomplishes much for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821836/in-c89-i-cant-seem-to-make-a-character-array-from-an-existing-one#comment92560965_52821836) about duplication of arrays.  Note a repaired `buffer[]` still relies on `envp[]` to know how many are valid in `buffer[]`.  I'd expect `buffer[]` to be 1 element larger for a `NULL`.

Comment: @chux or do something brave like, call me crazy, *retain the count of strings* in something besides `i` or enumerating `envp` *again*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buffer` is not the correct type to hold an array of strings.  It should be defined as:

```
char **buffer;
```

Also, you should `malloc` as follows:

```
buffer = malloc(i * sizeof(*buffer));
```

Use `sizeof(*buffer)` explicitly instead of the magic number 8, as a pointer is not guaranteed to be 8 bytes.  This is also prefered to `sizeof(char *)` as it does not depend on the type of `buffer`  Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Since `env` is terminated by a NULL pointer, you'll want to do the same with `buffer`.  You should also copy the strings with `strdup` instead of just copying the pointers so you can work on a separate copy:

```
char **buffer = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(*buffer));

for (i = 0; envp[i] != 0 ; i++)
{
    buffer[i] = strdup(envp[i]);
    printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
}
buffer[i] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

`char * envp[]` is an array of pointers to characters, not array of characters.  And a pointer (`envp[i]`) is an integer.  When you try to assign it to `buffer[i]` (which is a character), you get your warning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the feedback, I was able to fix my function after the comments here. Cheers for the help!!!

```
char **lower_env(int argc, char *argv[], char * envp[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int length = 0; /*Going to dictate lengths later on*/
/*creating the double buffer*/
char **buffer;

/* Finding the amount of elements in the environment array*/
while (envp[i])
{
    i++;
}

/* Allocate the memory for the Buffer to hold that amount of elements*/
buffer = calloc(i+1, (sizeof(char*)));


for (i = 0; envp[i] ; i++)
{

    length = strlen(envp[i]); /*Finding the length of each array pointed
                                at by the original environment array*/

    buffer[i] = calloc(length+1 , sizeof(char)); /*Allocating that memory space
                                                        within our buffer array*/


    /*copying over the arrays in lowercase pointed at by the env array to a new memory location
        pointed at by our new buffer array*/
    for (k = 0; k != length; k++)
    {
        buffer[i][k] = tolower (envp[i][k]);
    }
}

return buffer;
}
```